# LoaderManager does not accept 'this'

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, this, loader

Okay, I surrender. I cannot figure it out.

I'm following a Udacity course on Android Basics and need to figure out how to load data using a Loader. However, when I use the following line, the 'this' is highlighted in red and showing the following error:

```
Wrong 3rd argument type. Found 'com.example.carl.latestnews.MainActivity', required: 'android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<java.lang.Object>
```

I've googled, stacked and tried suggestion I've found. I've tried creating an inner class which implements the call backs. I've hit a brickwall and I'm sat here scratching my head trying to figure out what I'm missing!

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.carl.latestnews;


 import android.content.Context; 
 import android.os.Bundle; 
 import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager; 
 import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader; 
 import android.support.v4.content.Loader; 
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
 import android.view.View; 
 import android.widget.ListView; 
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<ArticleObject>> {

     // ArticleObject is a custom object which contains a headline, date, category etc of a news article

     // URL for Guardian API including API Key
     final static String GUARDIAN_API_URL = "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?";

     // API Key
     final static String GUARDIAN_API_KEY = "test";

     // ID for LoaderManager
     final static int LOADER_MANAGER_ID = 0;


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // Get or initialize loader manager
         getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_MANAGER_ID, null, this);

     }

     @Override
     public Loader<ArrayList<ArticleObject>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
         return new dataLoader(); // dataLoader() removed for easy reading
     }

     @Override
     public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<ArticleObject>> loader, ArrayList<ArticleObject> data) {
         / UI Update Code
     }

     @Override
     public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<ArticleObject>> loader) {
         // Reset Code
     }




 }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your `dataLoader` class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method expects LoaderCallbacks as an argument.

Your Activity needs to implement the [LoaderCallbacks interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html). 
OR
you provide an anonymous implementation of that interface like:

```
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks callbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {

        }

  getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_MANAGER_ID, null, callback);
```

Implementation of the interface methods is up to you though, this code won't work right away.

Comment: Hi Ascorbin. I've tried the above but the callback argument in the last line is highlighted and showing the same error???

Comment: @Caphson You need to be more specific about what the error is. Note that there's different versions of most of the loader stuff (normal and v4), check your imports if there's something mixed up.

Answer (score 15):

**Change:** `getLoaderManager()` to `getSupportLoaderManager()`;
Like this:
`getLoaderManager().initLoader(ID_FAVORITE_METAINFO_LOADER, args, this);`
**To**
`getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(ID_FAVORITE_METAINFO_LOADER, args, this);`

Comment: Thank you, I'm doing the same course as the OP.  Changing `getLoaderManager` to `getSupportLoaderManager` resolved my issue.