# AsyncLoader - wont accept 'this'

Tags: java, android, android-loadermanager

This is a follow up to a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836983/loadermanager-does-not-accept-this).

I have copied and pasted this code from [this tutoria](http://andreas-kluck.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/asynctask-and-asynctaskloader.html)l. When I paste it into Android Studio, the 'this' parameter of of content.getLoadManager.initLoader() is highlighted in red and shows the following error:

Wrong 3rd Argument Type. Found 'com.example.carl.loaderDemo.FooLoaderClient', requried: 'android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallBacks

I've ran into this previously (see first link). I was hoping this tutorial would help but I just seem to be going in endless circles!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?!

```
package com.example.carl.loaderdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

public class FooLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader {
    public FooLoader(Context context, Bundle args) {
        super(context);
        // do some initializations here
    }
    public String loadInBackground() {
        String result = "";
        // ...
        // do long running tasks here
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}

class FooLoaderClient implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {
    Activity context;
    // to be used for support library:
    // FragmentActivity context2;
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // init loader depending on id
        return new FooLoader(context, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {

    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        // ...
    }
    public void useLoader() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // ...
        // fill in args
        // ...
        Loader loader =
                context.getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);
        // with support library:
        // Loader loader =
        //    context2.getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);
        // call forceLoad() to start processing
        loader.forceLoad();
    }
}
```

Screenshot of error message:

[image]

Comment: try `FooLoaderClient implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallBacks` not `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` (Capital B)

Comment: maybe its missing some of the methods required by `LoaderManager.LocaderCallbacks`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch in your imports:

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
```

But you need

```
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
```

You cannot mix the support library with the android framework. Alternatively you can subclass `FragmentActivity` and call `getSupportLoaderManager()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're implementing `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` but the client is expecting `android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`. You need to be consistent in which loader API you're using.